# Toggle button state on form input using Knockout.js

Tags: forms, knockout.js

I have this form which has some basic input fields. 
By default, the submit button should be disabled, as the form shouldn't (and can't) be submitted when no fields contain a value.

I'd like to achieve that, using Knockout.js, the submit button automatically becomes enabled when an input field contains a value.

Here's the code I currently use:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: pname" placeholder="John Doe" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date of birth</td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option disabled hidden="" selected value="">Select a gender</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="f.e. Brussels" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="enable: pname.length &gt; 0" type="button">Filter by patient</button>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings({
    archived: ko.observable(false),
    pname: ko.observable(),
    pgender: ko.observable(),
    pcity: ko.observable()
  });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3SKz/)

Can anybody help me in the right direction? I'm a little stuck... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a computed variable, containing all your field checks (your validation, i check only on empty field):

```
self.checkSubmit = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.pname() != '' && self.pgender() != '' && self.pcity() != '';
});
```

Or create observable array of errors, and check button enabled on its length;

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="enable: $root.checkSubmit" type="button">Filter by patient</button>
```

See it on jsfiddle. Required fields insert by yourself. There: http://jsfiddle.net/T3SKz/1/ is only check on empty pname variable.

Comment: Works perfect. I'll modify it to suit my needs. Thank you!